# How do I add a csrf token to a json fetch in js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, django-templates, csrf-token

Every time I try to run the code, I get an error that a `CSRF token` is missing.

I have tried adding the token in the html and then adding an event listener for the form but that did not work as I still got the error and the console linked it to the line where I fetched a url.

Attempt: (the `{{ form }}` is a django form which contains a `textarea`)

```
<div id="add-form">
    <form action="" id="form-add">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h2>New Post</h2>
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Post" />
    </form>
</div>

// Javascript

document.querySelector('#form-add').onsubmit = submit // submit is the function with the fetch command
```

So instead I used `babel` to add the form into the html (this was not to fix the problem).

I have tried to manually add a `CSRF token` to the react form but I still got the same error:
`Forbidden (CSRF token missing.): /post`.

I also tried to add it using a JQuery function I found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#ajax) (django documentation) but it did not work probably because every time I added the `CSRF token` in the form I still got the error.

So how do I add a csrf token to a fetch command in javascript?

html:

```
<div id="add-form">
</div>
```

js:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.querySelector('#add-form'));


// Apps

function Form() {
    return (
        <div>
            <form id="form-add" onSubmit={submit}>
                <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="uhTD3vSjaOhnEC2Bda0bgRW5rzvFMTCRnQoX2aRDP2RDHMtP2YEqhaHDQvMbb9h0" /> 
                // attempt to manually add CSRF token
                <h2>New Post</h2>
                <textarea id='content' maxLength='500' required autoComplete='off' placeholder='Share something' />
                <input type="submit" value="Post" />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

// Functions

function submit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    fetch('/post', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'content': document.querySelector('#content').value
        }),
        // make sure the server knows this is a JSON body
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            // Add CSRF token

            // "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
        },
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
            // Print result
            console.log(result);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('Error:', error);
        });

    document.querySelector('#content').value = ''
}
```

Comment: Adding the token as <input> is useless unless you actually send it along in your fetch. You need to add it to the object you're sending as `body`.

Comment: Ok and how do I add it in? What do I add into the body object?

Comment: Put a comma after `.value` then add `csrfmiddlewaretoken: "uh..."` in the next line

Answer (score 0):

The code in documentation is correct - but, when your site does not have `{% csrf_token %}` template tag, it's not generated and thus it's not sent in cookies in user browser. Maybe you removed this tag and after you modified your javascript with code from django website.

You can also try to use `Cookies.js` library (or use code from stack overflow to copy cookies) and try to pass token like this:

```
headers: {
    'X-CSRFTOKEN': Cookies.get('csrftoken'),
}
```

For confirmation I can tell you that I use AJAX/fetch calls often in my code and everything works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

In your fetch function after the statement headers: insert "X-CSRFToken" see below the code:

function submit(event) {
event.preventDefault();

```
fetch('/post', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        'content': document.querySelector('#content').value
    }),
    // make sure the server knows this is a JSON body
    headers: {
        **"X-CSRFToken": "{{csrf_token}}",**
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        

        // "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    },
})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
        // Print result
        console.log(result);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('Error:', error);
    });

document.querySelector('#content').value = ''
```

}

Comment: Try to format your answer correctly, see how do I write a good answer [answer].